# mocha, chai testing for post in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js, chai

I am new to unit testing in node.js with sequelize.js. I followed [this tutorial to implement the api.](https://www.codementor.io/mirko0/how-to-use-sequelize-with-node-and-express-i24l67cuz) It is working fine and I need to test it for unit testing.
First I tried to test post operation for User class. Following code is to be tested using mocha.

```
// create a user
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {
User.create(req.body)
    .then(user => res.json(user))
})
```

My attempt is as below.

```
var index = require('../index');
describe('POST testing on user', function () {
 it('should add a row', function (done) {
    index.post('/api/users').send({ 'name': 'he' })
        .end(function (err, res) {
            chai.expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
            done();
        })
 });
});
```

Then it will give this error saying index.post is not a function. Where should I get wrong and how can I correct it to execute the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is quite wrong. It should be:

```
describe('/POST Create User', () => {
    it('Create User Testing', (done) => {
        let user = {
            'name': 'he'
        }
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .post('/api/users')
            .send(user)
            .end((err, res) => {

            });
        });
    });
});
```